# How do i simplify css with multiple id's

Tags: css

i'm trying to clean this CSS up a bit, since i want to apply the same style to it but it's messy. is it possible to simplify this?

```
#collection.shop-gioventu-new-york .container .twelve.columns,
#index .container .twelve.columns,
#index-v2 .container .twelve.columns          
{
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the markup and also tell us the reason why you need the id selector in the beginning. Is it  because you don't want to select `.container .twelve.columns` under a different parent? If yes, why not assign the others a common class? Also, how many such different parents do you have? If it is just one, consider using `:not()`. There are way too many unknowns here to give a complete answer.

Comment: This is why people are advised not to use IDs. Use a common class for all those elements that you're currently using ID selectors on.

Comment: I've cleaned a little bit, now looks better :-)

Comment: @Harry so I'm using the ID's because they refer to different pages. so just trying to target on these three pages. any way to make it neater?

Comment: @rs19: Your answer is in my previous comment and also Katana314's comment. Why don't you assign a common class and use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.fullWidth {width:100% !important}
```

In your html add the class="fullWidth" class to anything that needs this style.

```
<div id="collection" class="shop-gioventu-new-york container twelve columns fullWidth">...</div>
<div id="index" class="container twelve columns fullWidth">...</div>
<div id="index-v2" class="container twelve columns fullWidth">...</div>
```

'cleaning up' your css involves balancing between adding too many classes in your html or adding too many selectors in your css. You'll have to decide in this case what makes the most sense for your application.